# Mapeamento do AutoMapper retorna valores Zerados

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, automapper

Estou com o seguinte problema, ao executar uma consulta de uma `procedure`, a sua resposta ao ser mapeada retorna os valores das propriedades com valor nulo.

***Meu DataReader com o mapeamento feito pelo AutoMapper***

```
public List<T> DataReader<T>(string Procedure, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    var rows = ExecuteProcedureReader(Procedure, parameters);

    if(rows.HasRows)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true; cfg.AddDataReaderMapping(); });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        return mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<T>>(rows);
    }

    return null;
}
```

***A chamada do método***

```
var lista = conn.DataReader<Usuario>("PR_USUARIO_CONSULTAR", param);

foreach (var item in lista)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Nome);
}
```

***Minha Classe***

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Emdereco { get; set; }

    public string Cpf { get; set; }
}
```

Como posso fazer para que o AutoMapper possa mapear todos os registros dinamicamente.

**Obs: estou usando além do *AutoMapper*, o *AutoMapper.Data***

Comment: cara, ta meio confusa sua lógica, pq você colocou o return ali dentro do while?

Comment: @LucasMiranda opa é mesmo na verdade é um `if` , porém o problema continua. Ele não mapeia as propriedades do banco com a model.